# Same computational flow, but different functionalities

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Recently I wrote a small piece of code for my project need and the code works fine...

Below code is a generalized version....

```
if (someConditionX)
    {
        if (Utils.nullOrEmpty(string1))
        {
            Config config = getConfig();

            if (config != null)
            {
                doA();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doB();
        }

        if (Utils.nullOrEmpty(string2))
        {
            Config config = getConfig();

            if (config != null)
            {
                doC();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doD();
        }
    }
    else if (someConditionY)
    {
        if (Utils.nullOrEmpty(string1))
        {
            Config config = getConfig();

            if (config != null)
            {
                doE();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doF();
        }

        if (Utils.nullOrEmpty(string2))
        {
            Config config = getConfig();

            if (config != null)
            {
                doG();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doH();
        }
    }
```

I am not convinced the way it is written and I feel there is a scope for improvement to make it better........

Please give me some suggestions to make it better... Is there a scope to use lambdas ??.........

Comment: It is very much depending on the size and requirements of your project.. Please describe a wider context. What is `sitrng1` and `string2` what are the `do` functions, do you have many more strings or just these two

Comment: 1. do() methods vary w.r.t the strings(string1, string2, etc)... I don't want to get into the functional side of the do methods so skipped what do methods does.... All do methods are different....
2. There are more than 2 strings....

Comment: Is there a way to map between a given string to what do methods to execute? (assuming they are not ordered like you have here as `string1`, `string2`?

Comment: What is the commonality between doX, DoY, DoA etc ? Can those be  refactored into one method ?  Also if both `string1` and `string2` are null, do you need to initialize config twice ? or is that a valid option : `f(nullOrEmpty(string1) || nullOrEmpty(string1)) config = getConfig();` ?

Comment: No. there is no way to map strings and do methods....... I have edited my post... Please go through once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an interface like :

```
interface Do {
    void doSometing();
}
```

Implement it :

```
class DoA implements Do {
    void doSometing() {/* do A  */} 
}

class DoB implements Do {
    void doSometing() {/* do B  */} 
}
```

(`DoC`.......`DoD`......etc)

And use it by :

```
if (someConditionX)   {
     process(string1, new DoA(), new DoB());
     process(string2, new DoC(), new DoD());
 }
```

where process is defined by:

```
void process(String string, Do doA, Do doB) {

    if(nullOrEmpty(string)){
        if (getConfig() != null) {doA.doSometing(); }   
    }else {
        doB.doSometing();
    }
}
```

As for using Lambda expression, you could implement the interface using Lambda: 

`process (string1, ()->{/* implement doSomething */;}, new DoB());`

Comment: Thanks.. !! :-) :-)